# Change Network Adapter Setting to DHCP

Tags: windows, cmd, netsh

I'm trying to write a few short scripts with netsh. One to change an adapter to static addressing and one to change the same adapter back to DHCP.

I can get the adapter set with all of the correct static address settings with

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 10.61.1.253 255.255.255.0 10.61.1.1 1
```

This works fine. When I run the following command (a script) to switch back to DHCP I get an error message.

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

> DHCP is already enabled on this interface.

This is on a Windows 7 machine.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You might want to post this to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Windows 7. I found that if the link is down on the interface you are trying to modify, you get the message "DHCP is already enabled on this interface." If you plug a cable in (establish a link), the same command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while of "?" in the command to figure this one out as I had the same issue, but here is the syntax that worked for me in Windows 7: netsh interface ip set address **name**="Local Area connection"
**source**=dhcp

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work for me

Comment: This makes no difference and is just a shortcut to what the original poster did.

Comment: Well, a "longcut" rather.